# Oracle 19c, strange behavior grants in case of parallel execution

Tags: oracle

**Oracle 19c**, Grant execution on package for role is not enough in case of parallel execution,
have to grant direct to the user, don't understand why. Details below, please help....

1. There are 2 users: ETL and DQ.
2. In DQ package test_pkg was created:

Specification:

```
 create or replace package test_pkg
    authid current_user
    as
       procedure test_proc2(in_start number, in_end number);
       procedure test_proc;
    end  test_pkg;
```

Body:

```
create or replace package body test_pkg
as
   procedure test_proc2 (in_start number, in_end number)
   as
      v_id number;
   begin
      select 1 
      into v_id
      from dual ;
   end  test_proc2;
   
   procedure test_proc
   as
   begin
     begin
        dbms_parallel_execute.drop_task('test_task');
     exception when others then null;
     end;
     dbms_parallel_execute.create_task (
                      task_name=>'test_task'
                     );

     dbms_parallel_execute.create_chunks_by_sql (
                     task_name => 'test_task',
                     sql_stmt=> 'select 1 as start_id, 1 as end_id from dual',
                     by_rowid  => false
                    );
     
     dbms_parallel_execute.run_task
        (task_name      => 'test_task',
         sql_stmt       => 'BEGIN dq.test_pkg.test_proc2 (in_start=>:start_id, in_end=>:end_id); END;',
         language_flag  => DBMS_SQL.NATIVE,
         parallel_level => 1
                           );
  end;
end;
```

---

3. Create role etl_process, grant role to etl.

> ```
> create role etl_process;
> grant etl_process to etl;
> grant execute on dq.test_pkg to etl_process;
> ```

4. user ETL execute:

> ```
> call dq.test_pkg.test_proc();
> ```

5. after execution check user_parallel_execute_chunks and notice that
   chunk failed with strange error

> select *
> from user_parallel_execute_chunks
> where task_name='test_task'
> order by start_ts desc

ERROR:

```
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00201: identifier 'DQ.TEST_PKG' must be declared
```

6. when we grant execute to etl directly, everything is fine
7. If change procedure test_proc in package like below(remove parallel execution), everything is fine too.

> ```
> procedure test_proc
>    as
>    begin
>       dq.test_pkg.test_proc2 (in_start=>1, in_end=>1);
>    end;
> ```

---

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61952645/4808122) answer your question?

Comment: @marmite-bomber Thank you for your answer, but I can't understand one more thing. Quote from documentation in your answer - this is about additional requirement for compiling procedures/packages, not for invoking it, right? I'm just trying to invoke procedure from package that had already been compiled( –

Comment: See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/20/dbseg/configuring-privilege-and-role-authorization.html#GUID-5C57B842-AF82-4462-88E9-5E9E8FD59874) a more explicite documentation. E.g. *All roles are disabled in any named PL/SQL block that executes with definer's rights.*

Comment: @marmite-bomber, but in my example code is executed with invoker's rights (I used **authid current_user**) and in documentation I can see: _Current roles are used for privilege checking within an invoker's rights PL/SQL block_

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour is *neither strange* and nor relevant to *19c*.

See the link from the documentation of [`8.0`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A58617_01/server.804/a58241/ch7.htm) that describes:

> The owner of the procedure or package must have been explicitly granted the necessary object privileges for all objects referenced within the body of the code; the owner cannot have obtained required privileges through roles.

If you remove the `authid current_user` from the calling packakge you get the expected behaviour, both cases *direct execution* and the *execution through the package* `dbms_parallel_execute` lead to an exception `PLS-00201`

You may mitigate the former case with the adding of the `authid current_user` because in this case the role privileges are considered, but obviously you can't *inherit* the *current user* privileges in the `dbms_parallel_execute` package, so it continues to fail.